# Include python module (dependencies) installation in your python script

Tags: python, python-module

Is there a way to include/invoke python module(s) (dependencies) installation first, before running the actual/main script?

For example, in my main.py:

```
import os, sys
import MultipartPostHandler

def main():
    # do stuff here
```

But MultipartPostHandler is not yet installed, so what I want is to have it installed first before
actually running main.py... but in an automated manner. When I say automatically, I mean I will just invoke the script one time to start the dependency installation, then to be followed by actual functionalities of the main script.
(somehow, a little bit similar with maven. But I just need the installation part)

I already know the basics of setuptools. The problem is I may have to call the installation (setup.py) and the main script (main.py) separately.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the python version? python 2 or 3?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's python 2.7 Sir

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to include/invoke python module(s) (dependencies) installation first, before running the actual/main script?

- A good way is to use `setuptools` and explicitly list them in [`install_requires`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies).
- Since you are providing a `main` function, you also probably want to provide [`entry_points`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#entry-points).

> I already know the basics of setuptools. The problem is I may have to call the installation (setup.py) and the main script (main.py) separately.

That is usually not a problem. It is very common to first install everything with a `requirements.txt` file and `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Plus if you list dependencies you can then have reasonable expectations that it will be there when your function is called and not rely on `try/except ImporError`. It is a reasonable approach to expect required dependencies to be present and only use `try/except` for optional dependencies.

## setuptools 101:

create a tree structure like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── mymodule
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── script.py
└── setup.py
```

your code will go under `mymodule`; let's imagine some code that does a simple task:

```
# module/script.py    

def main():
    try:
        import requests
        print 'requests is present. kudos!'
    except ImportError:
        raise RuntimeError('how the heck did you install this?')
```

and here is a relevant setup:

```
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='mymodule',
    packages=['mymodule'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts' : [
            'mycommand = mymodule.script:main',
        ]
    },
    install_requires=[
        'requests',
    ]
)
```

This would make your `main` available as a command, and this would also take care of installing the dependencies you need (e.g `requests`)

```
~tmp damien$ virtualenv test && source test/bin/activate && pip install mymodule/
New python executable in test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Unpacking ./mymodule
  Running setup.py (path:/var/folders/cs/nw44s66532x_rdln_cjbkmpm000lk_/T/pip-9uKQFC-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///tmp/mymodule

Downloading/unpacking requests (from mymodule==0.0.0)
  Using download cache from /Users/damien/.pip_download_cache/https%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2F2.7%2Fr%2Frequests%2Frequests-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: requests, mymodule
  Running setup.py install for mymodule

    Installing mycommand script to /tmp/test/bin
Successfully installed requests mymodule
Cleaning up...
(test)~tmp damien$ mycommand 
requests is present. kudos!
```

### more useful commands with argparse:

If you want to use `argparse` then...

```
# module/script.py

import argparse

def foobar(args):
    # ...

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # parser.add_argument(...)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    foobar(args)
```

Comment: thank you very much for this comprehensive answer. greatly appreciate it dnozay

Comment: question though, what if my main expects arguments from argparse? Do I have to specify something under entry_points? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you would list argparse as a dependency or check for python >= 2.7, then in your `main` function, build the parser and call it. Instead of putting the code somewhere in the body of the module after e.g. `if __name__ == '__main__':` you would put it in a function that is exposed by `console_scripts`.

Comment: thanks a lot again. But hopefully, can you show snippet codes? If not too much to ask. Thanks

Comment: For those who are looking for the referenced links, can be found here: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#developer-s-guide

Comment: @dnozay would it be possible to have the same behavior (downloading required packages) but when you call `python setup.py build`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this. One way is to surround the `import` statement with a `try`...`except ImportError` block and then have some Python code that installs the package if the ImportError exception is raised, so something like:

```
try:
    import MultipartPostHandler
except ImportError:
    # code that installs MultipartPostHandler and then imports it
```

I don't think this approach is very clean. Plus if there are other unrelated importing issues, that won't be detected here. A better approach might be to have a `bash` script that checks to see if the module is installed:

```
pip freeze | grep MultipartPostHandler
```

and if not, installs the module:

```
pip install MultipartPostHandler
```

Then we can safely run the original Python code.

EDIT: Actually, I like FLORET's answer better. The `imp` module is exactly what you want.

Answer (score -2):

You should use the `imp` module. Here's a example:

```
import imp
import httplib2
import sys

try:
  import MultipartPostHandler
except ImportError:
  # Here you download 
  http = httplib2.Http()
  response, content = http.request('http://where_your_file_is.com/here')
  if response.status == 200:
    # Don't forget the right managment
    with open('MultipartPostHandler.py', 'w') as f:
     f.write(content)
    file, pathname, description = imp.find_module('MultipartPostHandler')
    MultipartPostHandler = imp.load_module('MultipartPostHandler', file, pathname, description)
  else:
    sys.exit('Unable to download the file')
```

For a full approach, use a queue:

```
download_list = []
try:
    import FirstModule
except ImportError:
    download_list.append('FirstModule')

try:
    import SecondModule
except ImportError:
    download_list.append('SecondModule')

if download_list:
    # Here do the routine to dowload, install and load_modules

# THe main routine
def main():
    the_response_is(42)
```

You can download binaries with `open(file_content, 'wb')`

I hope it help

BR

Comment: this answer doesn't explain why it is a good approach. I certainly wouldn't want my scripts to start downloading extra data and imports off the internet while they are running.

Comment: @dnozay I agree, I'll never write something like that mainly for security reasons ;) But sometimes, there is a little thing called reality, you know day work, bosses, clients... The good response is when the code works (my response). The best response is yours.