# is it possible to import pip modules from a file

Tags: python, pip

So basically i am making an auto clicker that needs pip3 modules to work eg.pyautogui,keyboard,mouse
would it be possible to make these modules install themselves when  a file is run, like a install.py thing that installs these modules so any computer can run my clicker.
thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include python module (dependencies) installation in your python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081948/include-python-module-dependencies-installation-in-your-python-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your specific example, you *could* have a python file that runs pip commands with the following:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["pip install module"])
```

But I think there are other approaches to what you are after that might be more recommended.

What you probably would find more useful is to look at some of the different options for running python programmes on other machines.

1. Making use of a virtual environment gives a way for other developers to easily get set up and run your code on other machines.
2. There are modules that turn python code into executables. Such as Pyinstaller, you might find this tutorial useful for that: https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/
3. You could also look into using docker (containerisation), which is similar to creating a virtual machine but with extra benefits

Answer (score 0):

You could create a python environment for your python file and install the required packages in it, so when you export your clicker along with its environment, you can run it anywhere.